# How to max $f(D)$ over the space where matrix $D$ is diagonal?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

I want to maximize some function $f(D).$

Obviously if there is no constraints, I can just form matrix $G$ by $G(D)_{ij} = \frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial D_{ij}}$  and solve $G(D) = 0$ for D.

However, if D is subject to constraints, for example D has {p,q} entries of D are fixed to  zero. How should I solve this problem ? Can I even use $\frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial D_{i,j}}=0 (i\neq p, j \neq q) $ at all ?

I guess my question is , should the gradient be affected by the constraint ?

Thnaks a lot.

Comment: Are you saying that you are minimizing $f$ over the space of diagonal matrices?

Comment: Yes! Thanks copper, I am going to modify my question. Sorry I don't know the rightful language to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create the matrix $G(D)$ where $[G(D)]_{ij} = \frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{ij}}$. If this is an unconstrained problem, then look for solutions to $G(D) = 0$.

**Addendum**: The domain in question is the set of diagonal matrices. Suppose $f$ is differentiable and $\Delta$ is diagonal, then $f(D+ \Delta) = f(D)+ \sum_i \frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{ii}} [\Delta]_{ii} + o(\Delta)$. It follows that the derivative is $DF(D)(\Delta) = \sum_i \frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{ii}} [\Delta]_{ii}$, which could be written as $DF(D)(\Delta) = G(D) \Delta$, where $G(D) = \operatorname{diag} (\frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{11}},...,\frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{nn}})$.

Comment: copper.hat : thank you very much for your help. Sorry I didn't make it clear in my statement.   I mean if D is of special forms (lower triangular, diagonal, banded, etc).  How should I solve it?

Comment: That's the explanation I was looking for !  Thanks a lot !. BTW: what is the name for this expansion $f(D+ \Delta) = f(D)+ \sum_i \frac{\partial f(D)}{\partial [D]_{ii}} [\Delta]_{ii} + o(\Delta)$  ?

Comment: First order expansion?